# How can I use an array of values as a jQuery selector argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have an array of classes/IDs and then on a click function using jQuery pass each of those values to that function to exclude them from the event rather than have numerous `:not` calls as I currently have which works but is a bit ugly to me.

```
 var excludes = [
          '#seeMore',
          '#readMore',
          '#isiToTop',
          '.btn-cta--download',
          '.videoModalTrigger',
        ];

        $(
          "a[href]:not('#seeMore'):not('#readMore'):not('#isiToTop'):not('.btn-cta--download'):not('.videoModalTrigger')"
        ).click(function () {
          _siteNs.Utils.deleteCookie('5_Signs');
        });
```

Comment: The whole concept (hardcode list of elements excluded from behaviour) isn’t exactly clean, though. What does deleting this cookie mean?

Comment: Yea that is true! A strange request from a client and how a page is built I have to set cookies but delete them conditionally. thanks for advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$("a[href]").not(excludes.join())
```